# Running STP and high-current AC cables together

Tags: ac, cables, twisted-pair

I am about to install a backup generator about 40m away from my house. There is no question what cables to run for the AC current (which will be 230V 50Hz up to 30A) — doubled 10AWG (6mm2) to keep resistance at acceptable levels at such distance.

But I do want to run a data cable along the AC cables: this will be needed for remote control of the generator, surveillance camera and what not. Obviously it would struggle to perform side by side with the AC cables so it will need to be shielded (STP, not UTP).

Setting aside any regulations/standards that would prohibit doing this, will STP cable work? Where would be the best place for it in the pack — in the middle (A), at the edge (B), or elsehow?:

[image]

Comment: Usually power and data are separated in tubes or cable tray with a separator. This isn't an option?

Comment: Usually is correct, in the US data cables and power MUST NOT be together in the same conduit (tube).

Comment: @Jeroen3 I would need to buy and bury 2 conduits instead of 1. Just wondering if there is sufficient _technical_ (vs regulatory) reason for it.

Comment: @Greendrake The technical reason is that in case of a fire, the power cables can short with the data cables, causing more collateral damages.

Answer (score 1):

Do not install power cable next to communications cable.

1. This is against the electrical code in most countries. In Australia, our Wiring Rules (AS 3000) specifically require power and communications cables to be physically separated, either by barriers or by distance.
2. If the power cable is damaged, and shorts to the communications cable, then the communications cable will be energized to the power voltage (i.e. 110 VAC or 230 VAC.) Communications devices are not designed to handle this voltage and may become live, posing a personnel safety hazard to anyone who touches them (i.e. you may kill someone.)